# Резервное копирование с mssql 2016 на 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть бд, создана на mssql 2012 потом, через резервное копирование перенесена mssql 2016. Так вот вопрос как перенести бд из 2016 на 2012. В параметрах бд ставлю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

уровень совместимости 2012, делаю резервное копирование бд, пытаюсь восстановить бекап в 2012, пишет что бд была создана в 2016 и не может быть восстановлено в 2012.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как перенести (attach или backup) бд с 2016 на 2012?

Comment: Такой поддержки нету. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042746/possible-to-restore-a-backup-of-sql-server-2014-on-sql-server-2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server не поддерживает миграцию БД с более поздних версий на более ранние. Базу можно перенести, [сформировав скрипт для определенной версии SQL Server](https://dzone.com/articles/generate-database-scripts-with-data-in-sql-server). В настройках генератора скриптов можно настроить версию SQL Server, для которой делается скрипт и указать содержимое скрипта.

Comment: Важно что таким образом рекомендуется переносить схему БД, данные желательно экспортировать в CSV.